# WTF select field showing value with round brackets on front end

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

In a nutshell, I am making a Flask-wtf application in which I have a select field as:

```
someVar=SelectField("someVar",choices=result)
```

where `result` is a list of data fetched from the DB.

Now the problem is on front end result showing values like ('abcxyz',) instead of just "abcxyz" whereas the DB query is also producing the value as simply "abcxyz". Also I want the dropdown as blank on page load.

I am showing this select field value on html as :

```
{{ form.someVar.label }}{{ form.someVar}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use QuerySelectField instead of SelectField, since you're fetching data from the DB to populate the dropdown.

`from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField`

So you'd do something like,

```
someVar = QuerySelectField("someVar",
                        blank_text='select someVar',
                        query_factory=lambda: Model.query.all(),
                        allow_blank=True)
```

Here you use `query_factory` to set the choices. Also note the `blank_text` attribute will make sure that no value is selected by default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as I am new to Flask, I am not aware of this approach much and I am just simply firing my query with the help of Sql Alchemy as : result = DBConnection.getConnection().execute("select SomeVarName from MV5")..........MV5 is a materialized view and I am not sure whether I need to make any model class for it or not. Could you please share an example with some details. That will be very helpful....Thanks

Comment: DBConnection.getConnection() is my python class method which is returning DB connection object.

Comment: Please can anyone solve my problem by giving an example ??

Comment: If you're using flask-sqlalchemy, you must be using ORM. Could you update your post with your model code that stores choices?

Answer (score 0):

The return value is a tuple.
Instead of

```py
someVar = SelectField("someVar", choices=result)
```

use

```py
someVar = SelectField("someVar", choices=result[0])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).